# Type inference in Knex when joining tables with same column name but different type

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

When joining two tables that share a column name but the columns have different types, Knex cannot correctly infer the type of the result.

```js
interface Author {
  id: number
  name: string
}

interface Book {
  id: string
  name: string
  author_id: number
}

await knex<Book>("books")
  .leftJoin<Author>("authors", "authors.id", "books.author_id")
  .select(
    knex.ref("id").as("book_id").withSchema("books")
    knex.ref("name").as("book_name").withSchema("books"),
    knex.ref("name").as("author_name").withSchema("authors")
  )
// -> type { book_id: never; book_name: string; author_name: string }[]
```

Any reference to `id` in the select will result in a type of `never`, although `name` will behave correctly because the types are the same in the two tables.

I was expecting `withSchema` to be used to infer the correct type. Even if I define a `'knex/types/tables'` module, it does not work. Is there any way to get type inference working nicely in this situation, or are explicit type annotations necessary?